# macports boost, but need an old version of boost

Tags: mac-osx, boost, libboost

I am not new to unix, but I am new to Mac OS.  I have seen that its pretty easy to use macports to get/build the tip version of boost.  But I need to get/build/install boost v1.41, not the latest boost.  That is because the test framework I am working with won't compile against anything newer than boost v1.41.  Though I would prefer to be able to bring the framework up to using v1.46 of boost, I am not permitted the time.

I know with Gentoo linux I can set a specific version of a lib/app that I want to emerge.  Easy stuff once you know how to do it.  With macports I can't find anything that is like that.

So my question:  How can I use macports to get/build/install boost v1.41?

Answer (score 1):

There's a link to MacPorts site where you can learn how to [install older port version](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort).

However your desire to use obsolete software versions would do you no good. It would be much better to fix your app then relying on specific version of third-party application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager?

You can recall older formula (install scripts) and edit formula to install specific versions pretty easily.

See the StackOverflow Question [Homebrew install specific version of formula ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)